# Is null check required here?

Tags: java, null-check

I come across this line of code in my project:

```
String statusRecoTime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

Then there is a null check like

```
if (statusRecoTime != null) {
     //do something
}
```

I think that the `statusRecoTime` will never be null and there is no need of this check because it is assigned with an object.

Please let me know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: The answer depends on whether `sdf.format()` can ever return `null`.

Comment: What does the documentation of format say? :)

Comment: What is your `sdf`, it's all depends on it

Comment: You don't need a null check. You do need a try/catch

Comment: I guess `sdf` is `SimpleDateFormat` which should throw an `Exception` when an incorrect value is tried to be formatted.

Comment: Always try to check the condition whether the value is coming or not. Likewise always write the code with try catch block. code standard always should be follow when you write code

Comment: The only thing you gotta be careful about is the usage of `Calendar`. The month is 0-indexed, which means that `Calender.set(2017,01,03,23,59,59);` returns 03rd February 2017. That's quite annoying.

Comment: It’s an aside, @JanesAbouChleih, and it’s true (except it is definitely not the *only* thing), and the good solution is to use the `java.time` classes instead of the outdated `Calendar`. Changing your old code in this way could be a project of its own, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `sdf` is a `SimpleDateFormat` instance, [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format-java.util.Date-) will never return `null`. The `null` check is completely unnecessary.

Various answers here concern themselves with whether that code will throw an exception. The only time it would is if `sdf` or `cal` were `null`. But assuming both are non-`null` and `cal` is a `Calendar`, that code won't throw an exception.

Comment: but if the `format` is done within `class.method1`, `method1` is catching the possible exceptions accordingly and the second code snippet is executed within `class.method2`, wouldn´t this `null` check be necessary again?

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy: That's making a lot of assumptions of information not present in the question. Also note that provided `cal` and `sdf` are not `null`, and `cal` is a `Calendar`, and `sdf` is a `SimpleDateFormat`, the code in question won't throw.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

From the [SimpleDateFormat docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition)), the method returns a `NullPointerException` if the passed date is null:

> #### `SimpleDateFormat.format()`
>
> Formats the given `Date` into a date/time string and appends the result
>   to the given `StringBuffer`.
>
> **Specified b**y:
>       `format` in class `DateFormat`
>   **Parameters**:
>       `date` - the date-time value to be formatted into a date-time string.
>       `toAppendTo` - where the new date-time text is to be appended.
>       `pos` - the formatting position. On input: an alignment field, if desired. On output: the offsets of the alignment field.
>   **Returns**: the formatted date-time string.
>   **Throws:
>       `NullPointerException` - if the given date is null.**

Checking `statusRecoTime != null` is not necessary, as you will have an exception if `null`.

Comment: Presuming `cal` is a `Calendar`, `getTime` will not return `null`.

Comment: You are right! We are presuming a lot of presumptions here ;P

Answer (score 0):

No you do not need any null check here as if **sdf** will not be able to format the time it will throw error instead of null. although as you are formating time of calendar exception will also not come if you have defined correct format in **sdf** .

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `sdf` is a `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

First thing to check is the documentation, as Mistalis already did in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43754279/5772882). The one-argument `format` method is declared in the superclass `DateFormat`, and the documentation says

> **Returns:**
> the formatted time string.

This should be enough. There is no mention that it could return `null`, so there should be no need to check. We could stop here.

If you want to be even more sure, we can check the source code for the Java version you are using. In Java 8 (and I would expect, in all versions) `format(Date)` calls a three-argument `format` method, gets a `StringBuffer` back and calls its `toString()` method. `StringBuffer.toString()` makes a `new String()`. `new` is guaranteed never to return `null`. So now we can be sure.

Except: An evil person might write a subclass of `SimpleDateFormat` in which `format(Date)` may return `null` in conflict with the documentation. Your `sdf` variable could hold an instance of such an evil subclass. You could get `null`. If you know from your code that `sdf` is always a `SimpleDateFormat` and not some homegrown or third-party subclass, we can rule out this possibility.